Matter development - Matter Accessory - Apple Ecosystem
What is the best way of logging the pairing / commissioning process of Matter and HomeKit Accessories (Console logs are encrypted / lacking).
I could not find any specific software or documentation provided by Apple regarding this (nor any other participant of the CSA).

Thanks for the edit to make this clear. If you try asking about development on stack overflow, make sure you document your code like this example where it shows how to read setup errors.
